# Avoid `delete[]` accepting an implicit pointer conversion?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, delete-operator, conversion-operator

I have a class with an implicit conversion operator to a pointer. Deallocating that pointer is not valid. Can I prevent the conversion to a pointer when used with the `delete[]` operator? I would like a compile time error. For the `free` function, I can delete an overload that takes the class as an argument.

```
void foobar(double*){}

struct A {
  // Please pretend I have a good reason for doing this.
  operator double*() const { return nullptr; }
};

void free(A&) = delete;

int main(){
  A a;
  
  // Just works TM
  foobar(a);

  // This compiles :(
  delete[] a;
  // This does not :)
  //free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

I think something clever would be needed for the desired effect.

---

A use case for implicit conversion: Say `A` implements a scoped array. Conversion makes `A` almost a drop in replacement for an alloc/dealloc pair. Templates and iterators requiring explicit conversion. Otherwise the call sites of c-like functions remain unchanged.

Comment: Although `std::free(a)` would compile even with your code

Comment: Do you need the conversion operator to be implicit? Marking it `explicit` would solve the problem.

Comment: You could add a `operator void*() const { return nullptr; }` to make it an ambiguous situation.

Comment: @Eljay That seems to be an answer! With limited use so far, I'm not seeing other inconvenient ambiguities either. Might still have some though. Side effect of  `-Wdelete-incomplete` existing instead of just being an error.

Comment: Do you really need a *conversion operator*, and not a simpler method? `double* A::toDoublePtr() const { return ...; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Probably better to go with C++20 [`std::to_address()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address) by specializing `std::pointer_traits` if applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can prevent the conversion to a pointer when used with the `delete[]` operator by making the conversion ambiguous.

However, depending on the situation of the rest of the code, this may cause undesirable ambiguity for the desired use cases.

```
struct A {
  operator double*() const { return nullptr; }
  operator void*() const { return nullptr; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it comes to stopping something at compile time you can think of using templates.

```
void foobar(double*){}

class A {
  // Please pretend I have a good reason for doing this.
  public : 
  operator double*() const { return nullptr; }
  template<typename type>
  void operator delete[] (void*, type size); 
};

template<typename type>
void free(void*);

template<>
void free<A>(void*) = delete;

int main(){
  A a;
  
  // Just works TM
  foobar(a);

  // Now this will not compile to ! :(
  delete[] a;
  // This does not :)
  //free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. Without `delete[] a;` I still get "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’" @ `void delete[] (`...Tried compiling with `g++ -std=c++17 foo.cpp`

Comment: Actually , I have mistaken, therefore I have modified my answer and this finally works

Comment: The updated version compiles even **with** `delete[] a;`. The defined `delete` is not a candidate to be called. I'm not sure there is a way to make defining that operator work.